# Assign Web App to an existing service plan in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to attach existing service plan to a new Web App in Azure Resource Manager template. The Service Plan is already up and running and not part of that arm template

Answer (score 3):

My service plan was in a different resource group so I also have to provide RG name

> "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('plangroup',
> 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-not-found#solution-3---get-external-resource)

Answer (score 2):

You've probably figured this out by now, but incase someone else clicks into this thread as I did I'll post this.

You can use the [resourceId function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#resourceid) to reference the exisiting Service Plan.

Then simply use this in the properties for `serverFarmId` in the template.

```
 "properties": {
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
  }
```

So basicalliy exactly what Fei Han example shows, but you need to remove the `dependsOn` (and of course the Service Plan resource).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to attach Web service plan to a new Web App in Auzre Resource Manager template. The Service Plan is not created by the same template

You said the service plan is not created, is it not an existing service plan? If you’d like to deploy both app service plan and web app to Azure via Azure PowerShell with Resource Manager template, please refer to the following ARM template.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "hostingPlanName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "skuName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "F1",
      "allowedValues": [
        "F1",
        "D1",
        "B1",
        "B2",
        "B3",
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "S3",
        "P1",
        "P2",
        "P3",
        "P4"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's pricing tier and instance size. Check details at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/"
      }
    },
    "skuCapacity": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 1,
      "minValue": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's instance count"
      }
    },
    "webSiteName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "HostingPlan"
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('skuCapacity')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('webSiteName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "Website"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('webSiteName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry I rephrased it. please check